# background-image not showing when uploaded to server

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

Having a problem with an svg file not showing up in my background after its been uploaded to a server I'm using. Made sure the file permissions allow it to be readable on the server and when I open my html file on my computer you can see it, but if you go to the url it doesn't show. Only browser we're working with is chrome. Any ideas? Seems strange since I didn't change anything before I uploaded it. Here's my CSS:

```
.paradox{
    background-image:url('paradox.svg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    }
```

and my html using the CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Homework 5</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body class="paradox">
<p class="spacing">
<iframe class="resize" src="form.html" frameborder="0" >
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is your page public? (can you share it)

Comment: Try CTRL+F5 - If browser returned 404 for image before you uploaded it then this might fix it. If not, see if you can browse to image `domain/path_to_image.svg`

Comment: @Onimusha I can browse to the image. Ctrl + F5 did not work though.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the SVG file is delivered with the correct MIME type.  Open the developer tools, go to the Network tab and load your page.  Open the URL of your SVG file and make sure the Type column says `image/svg+xml`.

If the MIME type is not correct, then add the following line to an `.htaccess` file in an ancestor directory of your SVG file:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
```

(assuming the server supports `.htaccess` files).

Comment: This was the case with my Media Temple DV server.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the wrong file path. Press `F-12` to open the debugger, open the NETWORK panel and reload the page. Look for a 404 error on that filename.

Comment: Came back with Status Code: 304 Not Modified.