# browser cant find background-image when uploaded to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, mime-types

When I run the following jQuery code, it works just fine, except that it cannot find the image. In developer tools on chrome I get a 404 error.

jQuery:

```js
$('.pg-nav a, .pg-nav-img').hover(
  function() {
    $('.pg-nav a').css('color', '#0087CD');
    $('.pg-nav-img').css('background-image', 'url(../images/page-nav-icon-blue.svg)')
  }, function() {
    $('.pg-nav a').css('color', '');
    $('.pg-nav-img').css('background-image', '')
  });
```

Looking at answers from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233133/background-image-not-showing-when-uploaded-to-server) I realized that the MIME type comes up as `text/html` instead of `image/svg+xml`. How can I fix this?

NOTE: It works just fine running off my pc, but once on the server I run into this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like with SVG you will have to set mime type via .htaccess. This site has more details [SVG MIME TYPE](http://www.w3.org/services/svg-server/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, although after inserting the .htaccess file, I still run into the same issue.

Comment: `.htaccess` is an Apache thing.  If you are not using Apache, you will have to configure the MIME type a different way.  If you *are* running Apache, then you may have to enable `.htaccess` files in your server configuration.